# Publishing 1st AngularJS2 error

Tags: angularjs

I have began studying AngularJS (wish me luck) and I am already running into a problem. Instead of seeing "My First Angular 2 App" I am seeing "loading ..."
I uploaded to the server - I am seeing My First Angular 2.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Well, no, we have no clue what's going on, as you haven't posted any code at all ?

Comment: well it works on a server but not on local machine